# How can I handle opening multiple modal Bootstrap windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The 2nd modal is called from a button in 1st modal. When the 2nd model is open and closed the 1st model become inactive. I can't even move the modal.

Comment: Bootstrap official [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) clearly mentions "Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code." So technically, you can do it, but for that you'll need to setup a fiddle showing exactly what you are after for us to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/fv-b-8-670/stacking-bootstrap-dialogs-using-event-callbacks) explains how you can achieve this.

> Using the `hidden.bs.modal` and `shown.bs.modal` event callbacks we can
>   keep track of the number of modals opened at a time. Given these are
>   modals and not dialogs, only one modal should be active at a time. The
>   rest should be disabled.
>
> I create a counter on the body tag for lack of a better place. Each
>   time a modal is shown I increment the counter and then decrement it
>   again when the modal is closed.
>
> Using this counter, I can quickly calculate a z-index for the modal
>   and it's corresponding backdrop that will be higher than any other
>   modal and backdrop on the page. This satisfies the 'disable everything
>   else' requirement.
>
> Setting the z-index of the modal is no problem, but finding the
>   corresponding backdrop div requires doing a search for tags with class
>   `.modal-backdrop`. To make sure I'm setting the z-index only on the
>   most recent one, I set the z-index and also add a `.fv-modal-stack`
>   class to it. Then when subsequent modals are opened, I look for all
>   backdrops that do not have a class of `fv-modal-stack`.

Here's some code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#openBtn').click(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
        });

        $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function( event ) {
            $(this).removeClass( 'fv-modal-stack' );
            $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' ) - 1 );
        });

        $( '.modal' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', function ( event ) {
            // keep track of the number of open modals
            if ( typeof( $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' ) ) == 'undefined' )
            {
                $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', 0 );
            }

            // if the z-index of this modal has been set, ignore.
            if ( $(this).hasClass( 'fv-modal-stack' ) )
            {
                return;
            }

            $(this).addClass( 'fv-modal-stack' );
            $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' ) + 1 );
            $(this).css('z-index', 1040 + (10 * $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' )));
            $( '.modal-backdrop' ).not( '.fv-modal-stack' ).css( 'z-index', 1039 + (10 * $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' )));
            $( '.modal-backdrop' ).not( 'fv-modal-stack' ).addClass( 'fv-modal-stack' ); 
         });
    });
</script>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
               <p>more content</p>
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
               <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
        </div><div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
          <br>
          <br>
          <p>come content</p>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal3" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```